# 403 forbidden error while installing

Tags: magento-1.9, installation

while installing magento manually I'm getting this error

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /multifacet/ on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

when I change the file name of htaccess to htaccess.1 the installation page come but it doesn't proceed further

Comment: You got a error in backend

Comment: You'll need the htaccess. Please check the file permissions. var, media and app/etc/ should be 777, rest of directories 775 and files 664. Owner should be tthe same as your ftp connection